# Pyenv getting stuck when installing Python version >=3.11 on WSL

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pyenv, python-3.11, python-3.12

I installed pyenv on Ubuntu (WSL) via the automatic installer and configured the Zsh shell as described in the installation manual. Now, I am trying to install Python version 3.12.2 and the command `pyenv install 3.12.2 -v` outputs the following:

```
/tmp/python-build.20240322165736.6755 ~
Downloading Python-3.12.2.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.12.2/Python-3.12.2.tar.xz
/tmp/python-build.20240322165736.6755/Python-3.12.2 /tmp/python-build.20240322165736.6755 ~
Installing Python-3.12.2...
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for Python interpreter freezing... ./_bootstrap_python
checking for python3.12... python3.12
checking Python for regen version...
```

After this, nothing happens anymore, even after waiting for an hour.

I already tried reinstalling pyenv and restarting my PC (Windows 11) which did not change anything.

It seems that `pyenv install` works for versions below 3.11 (tried with 3.9.18 and 3.10.13), but gets stuck after `checking Python for regen version...`  for versions above or equal to 3.11 (tried with 3.11.0, 3.11.8, 3.12.1 and 3.12.2).